# nav bar not collapsing using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using Bootstrap's Album template; and in doing so, to build my first web project, I don't know why my nav bar is bouncing up and down when I tap on the button.   Bootstrap HTML is identical, but working correctly.

a. On a larger screensize (for me), the button, once clicked, does not close the nav view. 
It just 'bounces'; it stays open and in view when I tap it, and never closes... just bounces up and then quickly reopens with every click.

I attached a few image files.  * I couldn't paste my HRML code in here so I have an image attached with the code. *

- my html file
- view on a larger screen (when I size the view up, the nav bar remains open.... clicking on the button does not collapse the nav bar view)

Thank you so much.   (*disclaimer: super newbie here.  So apologies for any mistakes in how I'm asking my question. Please give feedback on how better to do so in the future!)

Tanya

[My html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XjmU.png)

[UI on large screen where clicking button doesn't collapse nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L52FT.png)

Comment: Please create a [mcve], even one on jsfiddle.net would be useful. There's no reason you can't paste in your HTML into this question though.

Comment: as you have mention that you are newbie here.. you can go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first before asking a question :)

Comment: It looks like you're mixing Bootstrap [v3](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and [v4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/). **Please clarify which version you are using** and also post your code in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).